# Swift - How to get the Safari app's user agent string or build version programmatically?

Tags: swift, mobile-safari, wkwebview, user-agent

Our app is a shopping app that contains an in-app custom browser using WKWebView.

We occasionally have issues with some merchants for things like social auth *(Google/Facebook sign in)*, PayPal checkout, etc.

We have been able to fix this by setting a custom user agent override using the user agent string we get from Safari app *(by manually using safari app to go to a website that detects and displays the user agent, then copying that and setting it in our app as the user agent override for the `WKWebView`)*.

The only difference between the iOS WKWebView user agent and Safari app one is the end of the string: `Safari/604.1`.

**Example User Agent Strings from same device:**

**iOS WKWebView User Agent**
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3 Mobile/15E148`

**Safari App User Agent**
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`

Since the Safari "build version" *(currently 604.1)* may change for each iOS version, we need a way to dynamically get the correct one for any provided iOS version.

I have been unable to find any Apple API's that can provide this "Build Version".
The closest thing I have found so far is parsing the `Info.plist` for the `SafariServices` framework, but the build/version numbers it provides don't match what is displayed in the user agent string.

**Code**

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: SFSafariViewController.self)
let bundleId = bundle.bundleIdentifier ?? ""
print("Bundle Identifier: \(String(describing: bundleId))")
print("Bundle Info: \(String(describing: bundle.infoDictionary))")
```

**Resulting Info.plist**

```
"DTCompiler": com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0, 
"CFBundleSupportedPlatforms": <__NSArrayM 0x600000ce2f40>(iPhoneSimulator), 
"DTXcode": 1500, 
"CFBundleExecutable": SafariServices, 
"BuildMachineOSBuild": 22A380017, 
"CFBundleVersion": 8616.1.27.10.13, 
"UIDeviceFamily": <__NSArrayM 0x600000ce2f70>(1,2), 
"CFBundleNumericVersion": 0, 
"CFBundleIdentifier": com.apple.SafariServices, 
"DTPlatformBuild": 21A323, 
"DTXcodeBuild": 15A6160m, 
"MinimumOSVersion": 17.0, 
"DTPlatformVersion": 17.0, 
"CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion": 6.0, 
"CFBundleName": SafariServices, 
"DTPlatformName": iphonesimulator, 
"DTSDKName": iphonesimulator17.0.internal, 
"CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": en, 
"DTSDKBuild": 21A323, 
"CFBundleSignature": ????, 
"CFBundlePackageType": FMWK, 
"CFBundleShortVersionString": 17.0
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to somehow fetch the Safari App's user agent OR build version programmatically in our app?
2. Or is there another API or tool we can use to provide the device's iOS version and get a response containing the correct Safari app "Build Version"?

Comment: "We occasionally have issues with some merchants for things like social auth" Okay, sure, but do you really need the user agent of the *current* version of Safari? What are the "issues" anyway? Those services don't know what version of Safari you are running anyway. I don't see a problem with lying about what version you are actually using, as long as the version you say is not newer than the actual version.

Comment: Correct - The issues were typically either pages load blank, captcha's don't work, etc creating blockers for our users to continue browsing. And actually merchants websites DO care about the user agent. In fact one of our workarounds was using a static user agent from safari, which eventually got blocked by several merchant servers as it was flagged for suspicious activity - i.e. Why does one app have 100's of thousands of requests from the same exact device?